# Extracting weights and biases to a specific prediction in Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, keras

I have a neural network to classify the MNIST dataset. While I can extract the weights and biases for the model, I am curious to know if there are specific weights and biases for individual predictions. For eg, if I predict a specific image, 2 for example is it possible to get the weights and biases for this particular prediction? 
If so, how  do I do that?

Model -

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Please let me know  what additional information I need to provide for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, weights and biases are fixed while predicting, there is no such thing as weights and biases for individual predictions.

Comment: Okay thank you! This  is what I had thought as well, that for a single epoch the weights and biases should be  fixed...since that will give the lowest 'cost'. I am trying to generate adversarial images which discusses the need to extract weights for specific classes...hence the questions.